# How do I control which drive Ubuntu installs to?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have 2 320 GB drives on my computer. I have Windows 7 installed on Drive `C:`  How do I install Ubuntu onto Drive D, and still have dual boot capability?

Comment: Just a wild guess: you choose the correct partition to install it into during the installation.

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the "Installation type" window, choose the "Something Else" option. I don't remember exactly but I think it does let you manually make partitions for Ubuntu from whatever drive you want.